# Getting the first element of an empty Array

Tags: crystal-lang

Given an array which has zero or one elements, how do I return either the first element or nil?

I have working code, but it is not very elegant:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Model
  adapter sqlite

  table_name "categories"

  primary id      : Int
  field parent_id : Int
  field name      : String

  # return a category or nil
  def self.root
    roots = where(criteria("parent_id").is_null)

    if roots.empty?
      nil
    else
      roots.first
    end⋅
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply call [`first?`](http://crystal-lang.org/api/Array.html#first%3F-instance-method) on the array:

```
  def self.root
    where(criteria("parent_id").is_null).first?
  end
```

Comment: I thought `first?` would return a boolean, as in the Ruby convention.